# Regular expression to capture street name and optionally house letter

Tags: regex

I have the following address: `Castle street 103 B 30`. By using a regular expression I want to extract 2 things: `Castle street` and `B`.

So far I've got this: `([A-z ]+)`.
Which does what I want, except that it also includes the ending space of `Castle street`  and the surrounding spaces of `B`, which I don't want.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Use `[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*
\b[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*\b
\b\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*\b
\b[[:alpha:]]+(?:[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+)*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x8SmxM/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary (makes sure the first word is not glued to another word char, like letter, digit or `_`)
- `[A-Za-z]+` / `[[:alpha:]]+` / `\p{L}+` - one or more letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s+` / `[[:space:]]+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more letters
- `\b` - word boundary (makes sure the lastg word is not glued to another word char, like letter, digit or `_`)